# Highlighting for custom language in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions

**Background:**
I am learning how to create a custom language grammar to define syntax highlighting in VS Code using a tmLanguage.json file. I have added a rule for simple variables defined with syntax that looks like:

```
var myvar 42
```

where the word `var` is a keyword defined by the language, `myvar` is the name of the variable, and in this example `42` is the value assigned to the variable. I have been able to set up the regex/scopes to highlight variable declarations using the code shown below, but I do not know how to ensure that variables such as `myvar` are highlighted when they occur later in the source code.

**Question:** How can I set up this language in VS Code so that parameters such as `myvar` gets highlighted everywhere?

Here is the relevant section from the `mylang.tmLanguage.json` file:

```
"variable": {
    "patterns": [
        {
            "match": "\\b(var)\\s+([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\\b",
            "captures": {
                "1": {
                    "name": "keyword.declaration.mylang"
                },
                "2": {
                    "name": "variable.parameter.mylang"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

After reading [the VS Code guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide), I have seen that semantic highlighting can be enabled using the setting `"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true`. A [table](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#predefined-textmate-scope-mappings) is also given in the guide that maps VS Code's Semantic Token Selectors to various Fallback TextMate Scopes. I've tried to ensure that I'm using appropriate scopes - for example, the guide shows that the semantic token `parameter` in VS Code maps to the fallback TextMate scope `variable.parameter`. Unfortunately, the parameters were still not highlighted.

As the guide [further suggests](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#custom-textmate-scope-mappings), I then added language-specific theming rules to the contribution point in the language's `package.json` file:

```
"contributes": {
    "semanticTokenScopes": [
      {
          "language": "mylang",
          "scopes": {
              "parameter": ["variable.parameter.mylang"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also tried using other scopes, such as `variable.other.readwrite` but nothing I have tried seems to enable semantic highlighting.

Comment: Doesn't editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled imply that you have it implemented in a LSP server? You are using Textmate instead of LSP, right?

Comment: @kaby76 Are you referring to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#semantic-token-provider)? Where would I save such a file, and what should it be named? The docs are not clear on this.